# Laravel Eloquent Insert Multiple records only if one field is provided as an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, eloquent

Does Laravel / Eloquent provide a way to create multiple records with one call, if only one field is provided as an array?

For example I got $request coming in with data below, but only propIds will be exploded and provided as an array, all other values will be the same for the all new records.

```
{"_token": "kEKmrPzu4nCk35xJAMOgdl0kNdwUZvpECsBl91dH",
"propIds": "126,129,71,82,77,64,69",
"rate": "4",
"cost": "55"
}
```

I could do a foreach and build an array and then run `Model::insert($newArray);`
But maybe Laravel does provide a solution for if only one field is provided as an array. Thanks.

For now I am just using foreach loop to create array and then call `Model::insert($newArray);`

Inserting multiple records with `Model::insert($newArray);` **will not automatically add created_at and updated_at dates**. I added a timestamp as default value in the database.

Comment: No, you've to provide all the field values. Just map them before inserting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You need to use `insert()` and create a new array with this format:

```
Model::insert([
    ['prop_id' => 126, 'rate' => 4, 'cost' => 55],
    ['prop_id' => 129, 'rate' => 4, 'cost' => 55],
    ['prop_id' => 71, 'rate' => 4, 'cost' => 55],
]);
```

`insert()` will create just one DB query.

Answer (score 1):

you can bulk insert in laravel using `insert` method

first, implode the `propIds` and define an array to hold your data before insertion

```
propIds = array_explode(',', $request->propIds);
$insertData = [];
```

then use foreach to fill `$insertData` array and get ready to insertion

```
foreach($propIds as $propId){
$insertData[] = [
    "prop_id" => $propId,
    "rate" => $request->rate,
    "cost" => $request->cost 
  ];
}
```

now we have an Array of records, Ready to perform bulk insertion

```
Model::insert($insertData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override Laravel Models `create` function like below :

**Model**

```
namespace App\Models;

class YourModel extends BaseModel
{
  protected $fillable = [
    "_token", "propId", "rate", "cost"
  ];

  // override
  public static function create(array $attributes = [])
  {
    $propIds = array_explode(',', $attributes['propIds']);

    foreach ($propIds as $key => $value) {        
      $model = new static([
        "_token"  => $attributes['_token'],
        "propId"  => $value,
        "rate"    => $attributes['rate'],
        "cost"    => $attributes['cost']
      ]);

      $model->save();
    }
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
YourModel::create([
   "_token"  => $request->input('_token'),
   "propIds" => $request->input('propIds'), // "126,129,71,82,77,64,69"
   "rate"    => $request->input('rate'),
   "cost"    => $request->input('cost'),
]);
```

Comment: I think it would make more sense to define a new method, e.g. `createMany`, which leverages the existing `create` method internally. This leaves the original `create` method untouched for instances where it may be needed in the future.